# Finding the size of an intersection of subsets, given several other sizes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble with an old exam question that seems to follow a particular format. Essentially you are given a group of X people, some portion of which fall into one category, another portion of which fall into another and a larger portion (of both) fall into a third portion. The question is then which number of people fall into the first and second portion. The third detail essentially shrinks the relevant group size down. An example of this question can be found here (question 6):

http://cglab.ca/~michiel/2804/winter14exam.pdf

The question is how do you go about tackling such a problem?

Comment: Your question should be formulated more clearly; like this there is no way to answer it. I think you are given in a universe $U$ subsets $A$, $B$, and given sizes of $U,A,B$ and $U\setminus(A\cup B)$; you are asked for the size of $A\cap B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the size of $A\cup B$. Then use $|A\cap B|+|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$.